# Should I use MySQL 6.0 for my large project?

Tags: mysql, version, mysql6

MySQL 6.0 is for production. Can I use it for database storage of a large project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL 5.1 is the latest stable version, I'd recommend sticking with that. 6.0 will be quite unstable at this point.

**EDIT** as of 2011-05-26 MySQL 5.5.12 is the latest stable version. See this link for the lastest stable version: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 6.0 in this moment is a alpha version, so I suggest you to use the current stable release -> MySQL 5.1

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/6.0/en/full-table.html) you can find some info about the table size limit depending on operating System. MySQL has not internal limit.

Answer (score 0):

Only if there are critical enhancements that your site requires. And even then I'd hold back and use workarounds until it at least gets to beta.

Answer (score 0):

We tried to use the latest PHP and MySQL 5.1 with failure on an IIS7 machine.  I am sure if you download the source of PHP and compile it, it would have support for 5.1, but out of the box it seems to support 5.0.  So, we replaced 5.1 with 5.0 and everything worked flawlessly.

Short story is use what works well.  I would try it in development and avoid it in production until everything works well.